# iptables start on boot at Ubuntu 18.04 and cannot be removed

Tags: boot, startup

I have iptables starts on boot, and I couldn't remove it from boot list

it can be found on list, supposedly, inactive !

`systemctl list-units --type=service --all | grep iptables`

> ● iptables.service                    not-found inactive dead    iptables.service

I tried :
`update-rc.d -f iptables.service remove`
and
`systemctl disable iptables.service`
but I get :

> Failed to disable unit: Unit file iptables.service does not exist.

and on boot, rules are loaded, but I cannot find them on default paths, no files exist on  :

> /etc/network/iptables
> or any other path !

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the service in 18.04 is called "netfilter-persistent.service"

Comment: that was true, thank you for contribution